# C loading a const

Tags: c, constants

const arrays get loaded into flash, or else they are in RAM. 
How can I load a large const array, apart from typing in thousands of numbers by hand?
I am using the IAR compiler with an STM32F303 (Cortex M4)

Comment: You could convert the numbers to C code automatically, e.g. by writing a small script, or if you have a binary file of the data, by using something like https://code.google.com/p/bin2h/

Answer (score 4):

You always can write an application which will generate the array from what you need and then just `include` it in your source file.

Comment: That's what I would do, and probably will do if there is no other solution. What I would like, which AFAIK isn't possible, is to create the table from a local algorithm and then somehow declare it const.
Alternatively, find a way to tell the compiler (IAR) to put it in flash.

Comment: @DirkBruere The other ways is to write a linker script where you can tell the linker where to place certain sections/symbols of your code, or use compiler specific annotations if it's supported - you'll have to dig through the IAR manuals.

Answer (score 1):

What are the numbers? Typically you can use off-line tools to generate C code that holds the numbers in a `const` array of the suitable type. This is often done for i.e. look-up tables in embedded software, and so on.

You cannot do this at run-time, since it's the linker's job to arrange the segments of the program into the various available memory-blocks.

Also, flash memory is not generally "easy" to write, i.e. you can't typically expect to be able to have a regular C pointer into flash, and just write to it and have it "stick". Programming flash generally requires dancing with the flash memory controller, and keeping in mind things like block erasure, erasing time, minimum programming page size, programming time per page, and so on. Flash memory is not so much RAM, as it is ROM that happens to be reprogrammable in software if you know how.